# Установка таймера делфи

Tags: delphi

Здраствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать ручную установку таймера в делфи? Хочу чтобы можно было устанавливать любое время, например 10 мин через которое открывался бы ехе файл. (про ехе знаю что через ShellExecute). Прилагается картинка
[image]

Стрелками ставим нужное время. Можно ли сделать такой таймер и чтобы время назад шло?
Заранее Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дак а что сложного?

спроектироать форму вы можете.

по кнопке запуск

```
 Timer1.eneble:=true;
```

В событии OnTimer

```
dec(значение элемента);
элемент.repaint; 
if (значение элемента)<0 THEN 
 Begin
   timer.enable:=false;
     ShellExecute....
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

В ручную установить таймер с помощью edit:

```
timer1.Interval:=StrToInt (edit1.Text);
```

Interval измеряется миллисекундах (1000 мл. = 1 с.)

А что, бы шло назад - такое не знаю.... Я конечно не ас, но может через переменную зачудить?
Вот набросок:

```
var
a: integer;
begin
timer1.Interval:=StrToInt (edit1.Text);
a:= timer1.Interval;
label1.caption:= IntToStr (a);
end;
```

А на таймере ставим,что бы за каждый пройденный интервал, написанный в ручную, из переменной **а** вычитали это самое время. Всё расписывать времени - нет, ещё ошибусь где-нибудь, хотя задание действительно лёгкое. Фантазии больше)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать по-разному, но в любом случае, нужно знать, какой интервал лучше использовать. Свойство Interval стандартного таймера имеет тип Cardinal, т.е. максимальное значение = 4294967295 (Delphi 7). Так что, в принципе, чтобы просто отмерить время можно задать свойству Interval значение, равное введённому пользователем значению в миллисекундах, а в обработчике тика таймера записать:

```
{...}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click;
begin
  Timer1.Interval:=StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  Timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;
{...}
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer;
begin
  Timer1.Enabled:=false;
  ShellExecute(...);
end;
{...}
```

Т.е. отключаем таймер и выполняем программу.
Но если нам нужно сделать что-то типа часов или визуального таймера, то можно сделать Interval равный, скажем, одной секунде, и по тику таймера убавлять число оставшихся секунд, изменяя значения компонента, в который выводится время, например:

```
{...}
var i:cardinal; //глобальная переменная
{...}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click;
begin
  i:=StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  Timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;
{...}
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer;
begin
  Dec(i);
  if i>0 then Label1.Caption:='Осталось '+IntToStr(i)+'секунд.'
  else
  begin
    Timer1.Enabled:=false;
    ShellExecute(...); //или другое действие
  end;
end;
{...}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ Помогло